# How to handle exceptions in NEAR cross contract calls?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, rust-wasm

#### How can I catch and handle an exception in a chain of async call between contracts?

Suppose, that my transaction initiate the following calls:

```
contractA.run()
  -> do changes in contractA
  -> calls contractB.run()
     -> do changes in contractB
  -> then calls another method on contractA: contractA.callback()
     * callback() crashes
```

After an exception in a Promise, NEAR is not rolling back changes occured in past promises. I also don't see any method for handling exceptions in [near-sdk](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/1.0.0/near_sdk/env/index.html).

One idea would be to return errors instead of throwing exceptions and create bunch of private functions to update the state after error value and adding / releasing mutexes. However this won't solve  sometimes we can't control that, eg in external smart-contracts (eg, if `contractB.do` would panic in the example above).

Comment: Yes we currently have this issue where errors from promise are not exposed from runtime. Also as you mentioned, we lack this "update" abstraction to the contract state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to catch an exception is to have a callback on the promise that generated the exception.

In the explained scenario, the `contractA.callback()` shouldn't crash. You need to construct the contract carefully enough to avoid failing on the callback. Most of the time it's possible to do, since you control the input to the callback and the amount gas attached. If the callback fails, it's similar to having an exception within an exception handling code.

Also note, that you can make sure the `callback` is scheduled properly with the enough gas attached in `contractA.run()`. If it's not the case and for example you don't have enough gas attached to `run`, the scheduling of callback and other promise will fail and the entire state from `run` changes is rolled back.
But once `run` completes, the state changes from `run` are committed and `callback` has to be carefully processed.

We have a few places in `lockup` contract where the callback is allowed to fail: https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/6fb13584d5c9eb1b372cfd80cd18f4a4ba8d15b6/lockup/src/owner_callbacks.rs#L7-L24

And also most of the places where the callback doesn't fail: https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/6fb13584d5c9eb1b372cfd80cd18f4a4ba8d15b6/lockup/src/owner_callbacks.rs#L28-L61

---

To point out there are some situation where the contract doesn't want to rely on the stability of other contracts, e.g. when the flow is `A --> B --> A --> B`. In this case `B` can't attach the callback to the resource given to `A`. For these scenarios we were discussing a possibility of adding a specific construct that is an atomic and has a resolving callback once it's dropped. We called it `Safe`: https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/pull/26

---

#### EDIT

> What if `contractB.run` fails and I will like to update the state in `contractA` to rollback changes from `contractA.run`?

In this case `contractA.callback()` is still called, but it has `PromiseResult::Failed` for its dependency `contractB.run`.

So `callback()` can modify the state of `contractA` to revert changes.

For example, a callback from the lockup contract implementation to handle withdrawal from the staking pool contract: https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/6fb13584d5c9eb1b372cfd80cd18f4a4ba8d15b6/lockup/src/foundation_callbacks.rs#L143-L185

If we adapt names to match the example:

The lockup contract (`contractA`) tries to withdraws funds (`run()`) from the staking pool (`contractB`), but the funds might still be locked due to recent unstaking, so the withdrawal fails (`contractB.run()` fails).
The callback is called (`contractA.callback()`) and it checks the success of the promise (of `contractB.run`). Since withdrawal failed, callback reverts the state back to the original (reverts the status).

Actually, it's slightly more complicated because the actual sequence is `A.withdraw_all -> B.get_amount -> A.on_amount_for_withdraw -> B.withdraw(amount) -> A.on_withdraw`

Comment: Thanks for answering! Make sense with `contractA.callback`. What if `contractB.run` fails and I will like to update the state in `contractA`  to rollback changes from `contractA.run`?

Comment: Added to the answer